# Make a default route in Angular 2 router 3.0

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm making an app which contains a lot of routes. I'm thinking about making an default route which would redirect users who enter the route that doesn't exists. I've done search for it, but everything seems hopeless. Is it even supported in **router 3.0**?

The latest code I found and tried:

```
{
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundComponent
}
```

Seems to not work for me. Any ideas?

I'm building in **rc4** now, I'll be updating everything to rc6 in some time.

**UPDATE**: 
The following route is redirecting every route to NotFoundComponent, while I want it to redirect just not-existing routes.

Comment: That's the way to go. Please provide more information about what doesn't work or how it doesn't work for you.

Comment: updated. Thanks for warning I accidentally forgot to write what is it doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of routes is relevant. You need to move this catch-all route to the last position, otherwise it matches before any other route.

Comment: Now I realized it. Thank you. Will mark as correct in few.